# Simplifying case statement for network script

Tags: bash, shell, network-programming

I am working on a networking script that will help identify what gateway exists depending on the local network it's on. It will echo back what location I'm from given the gateway.

Is there any way I can simplify the script? I know there are multiple methods of going about writing this. For example, creating an `array` for a list of elements for each gateway or the simple `if then` clause after declaring a variable for each gateways. What is the most efficient and simplest?

```
GW=$(route get default | grep gateway | awk '{ print $2 }')

case ${GW} in
  10.0.1.1
    echo "US"
    ;; 
  10.0.2.2
    echo "CN"
    ;;  
  10.1.2.1 
    echo "UK"
    ;; 
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `associative array` would bring the least biolerplate.

```
declare -A ARR  # to make it associative
ARR["10.0.1.1"]="US"
ARR["10.0.2.2"]="CN"
ARR["10.1.2.1"]="UK"

echo ${ARR[$GW]:-"unknown gateway"}  # ":-" (Use Default Values) for missing key
```

Check out `man bash` for more on this.

Comment: haven't used associated arrays for this particular application before but this is a very elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: I also like to add that associative arrays will only work in the latest version of bash 4. I am running into a `ARR: bad array subscript` error.

Comment: If you only need to echo then a few rows like `[[ $GW = "10.0.1.1" ]] && echo US` might not be that ugly either. This works under bash3 too.